# How best to set output directory for a CMake C++ project built by Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I have used Visual Studio 2017 to build C++ desktop projects using .vcxproj files.  I like the default behavior where the output directory is a subdirectory below the project. For example:

```
|-myproj.sln
|-myproj.vcxproj
|-----------------|--x64 --|-- myproj_release --|-- myproj.exe
```

I now want to define the build using CMake instead of .vcxproj, so that I can build with Visual Studio Code as an alternative to Visual Studio 2017.

I converted my .vcxproj to a CMake project using cmake-converter. The resulting CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
  set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUT_DEBUG}")
  set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUT_DEBUG}")
  set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUT_DEBUG}")
else()
  set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUT_REL}")
  set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUT_REL}")
  set(CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUT_REL}")
endif()
```

When I open this CMakeLists.txt with Visual Studio 2017 and build it, it puts the executable in subdirectory CMakeBuilds of my user directory.  I guess this is because Visual Studio 2017 is determining CMAKE_BINARY_DIR.

What is the best way of getting the output directory to be in the source directory as happens with my .vcxproj file?

Comment: Try replacing CMAKE_BINARY_DIR with CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR

Comment: That made no difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer for my question is to modify buildRoot in CmakeSettings.json:

```
"buildRoot": "${workspaceRoot}\\build\\${name}"
```

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio is a **multiconfiguration** generator. That is, it configures the project for **several configurations at once**. Because of that, when using such generators the variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` doesn't contain the configuration name, it is simply empty.

By default, with multiconfiguration generators, variables like `CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` are automatically [appended with per-configuration subdirectory](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_tgt/LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html). There are two ways to handle this behaviour:

1. Use [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#manual:cmake-generator-expressions(7)) when defining the variable. That expression may be evaluated conditionally, depended on the configuration type. E.g.:

   ```
    # For Debug configuration this will be evaluated to
    #   '${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUT_DEBUG}'
    # For Release configuration this will be evaluated to
    #   '${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUT_REL}'
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/$<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:${OUTPUT_DEBUG}>$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:${OUTPUT_REL}>")
   ```
2. Use `_<CONFIG>` versions of the variable. E.g.:

   ```
    # Output directory for libraries in Debug configuration
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUT_DEBUG})
    # Output directory for libraries in Release configuration
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${OUTPUT_REL})
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.

Comment: I don't think this is quite answering my question. The answer shown puts the output directories below CMAKE_BINARY_DIR but that is subdirectory CMakeBuilds of my user directory, whereas I want it to be below my source directory.  Do I need to change CMake's working directory path in some way?

Comment: Hm, If you want to place libraries below the source directory, why do you use `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` variable in your code? Just use `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`, which refers to the source directory of your project.