# Visual Studio 2017 and CMake - How to set the build directory

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I use Visual Studio 2017. I have noticed that the CMake build directory is placed in some place other than my project folder:

```
C:\Users\User\CMakeBuilds\"some id"
```

I would like to have the CMake build directory in my project folder. How can I achieve this?

**Edit:**
I have just created a basic CMakeLists.txt using notepad:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project (TestCpp)
add_executable(testCpp main.cpp)
```

I open it in Visual Studio using the File > Open > Folder options.

Comment: How did you set up your project? Did you run CMake then open your generated Visual Studio solution? Did you open Visual Studio and create a CMake project? Please add more details to your question post about your project setup and any *specific* commands you ran to achieve this.

Comment: Please see Edit.

Comment: Just realizing this is likely a duplicate question: see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56497784/3987854).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/customize-cmake-settings?view=vs-2017) on the Microsoft website, you can change your **Build** directory by modifying the *CMakeSettings.json* file. This file will be located in your root project directory, so you can open it by double-clicking it in the **Solution Explorer**. It may show the **CMake Settings** screen, so you can click the highlighted *CMakeSettings.json* text at the top to edit the underlying file. It should look something like this:

```
{
  "name": "x86-Debug",
  "generator": "Ninja",
  "configurationType": "Debug",
  "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x86" ],
  "buildRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\build\\${name}",
  "installRoot": "${env.USERPROFILE}\\CMakeBuilds\\${workspaceHash}\\install\\${name}",
  "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
  "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
  "ctestCommandArgs": ""
},
```

So just change the `buildRoot` value to where you want Visual Studio to place your **Build** directory, save your changes, and Visual Studio should automatically re-run CMake to apply the changes.

On some configurations, the `buildRoot` already defaults to a location within your project:

```
  "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build2\\${name}",
```

but in other cases, it will use a path in the current user's home directory.